# Document Schema Performance

Tags: couchdb

I am trying to determine the best document schema for a project for couchdb (2.3.1). In researching this I am finding some conflicting information and no relevant guidelines for the latest version of couchdb and similar scenarios. If this data does not lend itself to couchdb or a different method other than whats detailed below is prefered, I would like to better understand why.

My scenario is to track the manufacturing details of widgets:

1. 100,000-300,000 widget types must be tracked
2. Each widget type is manufactured between 200-1,800 times a day
3. Widget type manufacturing may burst to ~10,000 in a day
4. Each widget creation and its associated details must be recorded and updated
5. Widget creation is stored for 30 days
6. Query widget details by widget type and creationStartTime/creationEndTime
7. I am not concerned with revisions, and can just update and use the same _rev if this may increase performance

**Method 1:**

```
{
    "_id": "*",
    "_rev": "*",
    "widgetTypeId": "1831",
    "creation": [{
        "creationId" "da17faef-3591-4579-b5f6-ff0a719a6da7",
        "creationStartTime": 1556471139,
        "creationEndTime": 1556471173,
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "styleId": "92811",
        "creatorId": "82812"
  },{
        "creationId" "893fede7-3874-44ed-b290-7001b4901bc9",
        "creationStartTime": 1556471481,
        "creationEndTime": 1556471497,
        "color": "#cccccc",
        "styleId": "75343",
        "creatorId": "3211"
  }]
}
```

Using method one would limit my document creation to 100,000-300,000 documents. However, these documents would be very tall and frequently updated.

**Method 2:**

```
{
    "_id": "*",
    "_rev": "*",
    "widgetTypeId": "1831",
    "creationId" "da17faef-3591-4579-b5f6-ff0a719a6da7",
    "creationStartTime": 1556471139,
    "creationEndTime": 1556471173,
    "color": "#ffffff",
    "styleId": "92811",
    "creatorId": "82812"
},{
    "_id": "*",
    "_rev": "*",
    "widgetTypeId": "1831",
    "creationId" "893fede7-3874-44ed-b290-7001b4901bc9",
    "creationStartTime": 1556471481,
    "creationEndTime": 1556471497,
    "color": "#cccccc",
    "styleId": "75343",
    "creatorId": "3211"   
}
```

Method 2 creates a tall database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common problem to be faced with. In general terms, small, immutable documents will likely be more performant than few, huge, mutable documents. The reasons for this include:

1. There is no support for partial updates (patch) in CouchDB. So if you need to insert data into an array in a big document, you need to fetch all of the data, unpack the json, insert the data, repack the json and send the whole thing back to CouchDB over the wire.
2. Larger documents provide for more internal overheads, too, especially when it comes to indexing.

It's best to let the data that *change* as a unit make up a document. Ever-growing lists in documents is a bad idea.

It seems to me that your second alternative is a perfect fit for what you want to achieve: a set of small documents that can be made immutable. Then make a set of views so you can query on time ranges and widget type.